# Using 'exec' in bash_profile stops login shell

Tags: bash, exec, linux-from-scratch

I'm creating the following .bash_profile (from [linuxfromscratch guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/settingenvironment.html)) for lfs user:

```
exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
```

When executing `su - lfs` I get:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 su - lfs
```

Executing `fg` resumes lfs' user shell. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `exec` executes the code in the current process. Normally a command is executed in a child shell/environment. Try the following:

```sh
$ bash        # open second shell
$ exec false  # close second shell
$ echo $?     # get exit code
$ exit        # close terminal
```

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/exec.1p.html) isn't really helpful here. I often use `exec` if I run a script through a Qt process and it should end after some period of time, regardless whether the command if finished or not.

Comment: I still don't understand why, in my bash_profile scenario, the process executing `su - lfs` gets *stopped* and we get back to the parent process. This is not supposed to happen, this should work according to linuxfromscratch instructions.

Comment: If you would to source .bash_profile, what happens? `source .bash_profile; su root`.

Comment: That works as expected, a new shell is spawned and the "su root" command is ignored.

Comment: Try to remove `exec`. I don't know why your problem occurs, but I think `exec` is redundant.

Comment: Yes that works, but the point of using `exec` here is to ensure a 'clean' environment (see www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/settingenvironment.html),

Comment: The `-i` option already ensures this. `exec` only executes commands in the current shell instead of a new one. In `man env` they state `-i, --ignore-environment: start with an empty environment`. I think you can dismiss the `exec`. Otherwise you missed an error earlier on. LFS is not bug free. It was my graduation assignment years ago and I ran into an issue too.